# Cannot coerce class ....to a data.frame error

Tags: r

R subject

I have an "cannot coerce class "c("summary.turnpoints", "turnpoints")" to a data.frame" error when trying to save the summary in a file. I have tried to fix that with as.data.frame with no success.

code :

```
library(plyr)
library(pastecs)

 data <- read.table("C:\\Users\\Ron\\Desktop\\dataset.txt", header=F, col.name="A")
 data.tp=turnpoints(data$A)
 print(data.tp)
```

Turning points for: data$A

```
nbr observations  : 5990 
nbr ex-aequos     : 51 
nbr turning points: 413 (first point is a pit)
E(p) = 3992 Var(p) = 1064.567 (theoretical)
```

Turning points for: data$A

```
nbr observations  : 5990 
nbr ex-aequos     : 51 
nbr turning points: 413 (first point is a pit)
E(p) = 3992 Var(p) = 1064.567 (theoretical)


 data.sum=summary(data.tp)
 print(data.sum)

    point type        proba      info
1      11  pit 7.232437e-15  46.97444
2      21 peak 7.594058e-14  43.58212
3      30  pit 3.479857e-27  87.89303
4      51 peak 5.200612e-29  93.95723
5      62  pit 7.594058e-14  43.58212
6      70 peak 6.213321e-14  43.87163
7      81  pit 6.276081e-16  50.50099
8      91 peak 5.534016e-23  73.93602
.....................................

write.table(data.sum, file = "C:\\Users\\Ron\\Desktop\\datasetTurnP.txt")

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("summary.turnpoints", "turnpoints")" to a data.frame
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘plyr’ was built under R version 3.0.1 
2: package ‘pastecs’ was built under R version 3.0.1
```

How can I save these summary results to a text file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Value section of:

```
?pastecs::summary.turnpoints
```

It should be clear that this will not be a set of lists all of which have the same length. Hence the error message. So rather than asking for the impossible, ... tell us what you wanted to save.

It's actually not impossible, just not possible with `write.table`, since it's not a dataframe. The `dump` function would allow you to construct an ASCII representation of the `structure(...)` representation of that summary-object.

```
dump(data.sum, file="dump_data_sum.asc")
```

This could then be `source()-ed`

Comment: With :
>dump(data.sum, file="dump_data_sum.asc")
I get :
Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : invalid first argument

Comment: Perhaps you have S4 objects in there. In which case you need to use `save`.

Comment: I could save the asc file. Reading it with : table <- data.frame(readAsciiGrid("C:\\Users\\ernest\\Desktop\\Forecast_NN\\dump_data_sum.asc"))
Error in readAsciiGrid("C:\\Users\\ernest\\Desktop\\Forecast_NN\\dump_data_sum.asc") : 
  object 'cellsize' not found

Comment: Without "dataset.txt" and a better description of what youa ctually wnat, this is too much of a guessing game.

Comment: OK. I think I have just to copy-paste the results. Thank you anyway.